# How to properly get URL's html code with selenium webdriver and python?

Tags: python, csv, selenium, web-crawler

With python 2.7 and selenium webdriver I'm trying to: open URLs from a CSV file (csv contains 1 url per line), read the URL's DOM html code, extract keywords from here and print the results:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import csv

keyword = ['script']

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Jacob\PycharmProjects\Testing\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
html = driver.page_source

with open('listofwebsites.csv', 'r') as f:
    csv_f = csv.reader(f, lineterminator='\n')
    for line in f:
        strdomain = line.strip()
        if '.nl' in strdomain:
            try:
                driver.get(strdomain)
                for searchstring in keyword:
                    if searchstring.lower() in html.lower():
                        print (strdomain, keyword, 'found')
                    else:
                        print (strdomain, keyword, 'not found!')

            except strdomain.HTTPError:
                print (strdomain, 'HTTP ERROR')

            except strdomain.URLError:
                print (strdomain, 'URL ERROR')

            except strdomain.socket.error:
                print (strdomain, 'SOCKET ERROR')

            except strdomain.ssl.CertificateError:
                print (strdomain, 'SSL Certificate ERROR')    
f.close()
```

A snippet of the printed results:

```
('http://www.google.nl', ['script'], 'not found!')
('http://www.marktplaats.nl', ['script'], 'not found!')
('http://www.ing.nl', ['script'], 'not found!')
```

Obviously my script isnt functioning well in terms of reading the DOM since `script` does exist within the website's DOM html code.

How can i fix this?

Comment: you never use `csv_f`

Comment: @ryugie what do you mean?

Comment: @jakeT888 you create a csv reader, `csv_f` on line 10. Then, online 11 you ignore your `csv_f` reader object and instead iterate directly through your file object `f. Therefore, your csv reader is never used for anything.

Comment: Also - if you're simply pulling the html code and checking it, do you even need selenium? Selenium is used for **interacting** with websites - filling out forms, clicking on things, interacting with the JS on the page etc. What you're doing here seems to be just extracting the page HTML and checking stuff, so a much simpler approach would be to use the `requests` module. You can retrieve the page HTML with `requests` without having to start an entire web driver / browser combo, it'll be a much faster & cleaner approach.

Comment: @daveruinseverything thank you for your reply. How would you suggest that I edit my code exactly? I've tried urllib2 for example to get the page html. However, using this I got the "View page source"-code instead of the javascript rendered DOM html code (which im looking for), thats why I use selenium (i dont know better sorry). Can I get the DOM also with `requests` then?